# Challenges linking to Facebook account with a different email address

Tags: .net, sql, asp.net-mvc, facebook

How should I deal with users connecting their account on my website to their FB account, when their fb email does not match their user account's email in my DB?  Do I ignore their fb email, and then just associate their FB id with the email I have for them?  Or do I create a new account with the fb email and fb id?

Also, if I wanted to allow users to link their account on my website with multiple email addresses what's the best way to design the DB for this?  Do I need an Emails table that has a foreign key relationship to the Users table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a Facebook developer, you do not have access to a user's Facebook account email address unless they specifically [grant you extended permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/).  In practice, this is a rare event, so it is best to build your local system without any reliance on a user's Facebook email address.  The only thing you can count on is their Facebook ID.

Build your website so that when a user links their Facebook account to the account on your website, you associate the website account with the Facebook ID.  That should be all you need.  The easiest way is to simply add something like a `facebook_id` column to your users table and put an index on it.  That way you can look up a local website account via a Facebook ID.

If you want to store multiple email address that you collect locally from your website, then a `users_email` table with a foreign key to the `users` table would be a good idea.  You could probably work in the extended permissions into this table in the event that you do go ahead and try to get users to grant you email permissions.

Comment: Thanks, you bring up a good point, although it's a battle between an easier user experience and higher facebook connect conversion.  I think I may do something in between--if it's a new user, request the email address, if not, no need for the email.